How to protect a 32mm composite pipe in a 35mm hole through floor?
I have a 35mm hole through a 35cm thick floor. The floor has old tiles on top (~25mm thick) plus some kind of hollow bricks underneath. I'm not sure of the precise makeup of the floor.
I've fitted a 32mm composite pipe (pex-alu-pex) for hot water through the floor. But now I'm realising the expansion and contraction of the pipe means it will probably rub on the sides of the hole. I'd like to prevent that. I had to bend the pipe in place, so taking it out would be a hassle. I haven't pressed the fittings yet though, so if I have to take it out and replace it, I could do that.
I could try adding a pipe sleeve, but I'm not sure if I have enough space, there's only ~3mm to play with.
Can I use any kind of expanding foam to seal the pipe in place and absorb the expansion / contraction? I don't have any experience with sealing foams, so I don't know if I can spray it into a 35mm hole with only ~1.5mm space around the pipe.
Is there any other kind of sealing material that I could pour in as a liquid from the top? I could close the hole at the bottom, so I could pour a liquid and then let it set around the pipe potentially. But it might end up filling the hollow bricks instead.

Get a tube of polyurethane sealant and, using a caulking gun,  apply it to both sides of the opening.

Even 3mm clearance may be enough for something like teflon sheet.  Is bore smooth?  Do you actually need to seal the top and bottom of the penetration?

@DelphicOracle I thought about using sealant top and bottom, and hoping the pipe will stay roughly central in the hole. Thanks for the suggestion.

@Huesmann The bore is not smooth, there's multiple layers of brick, I'm not sure what the inside of the hole looks like. I don't think I need to seal both top and bottom, probably just the top with some silicone sealant would suffice. I'm concerned about the pipe rubbing. Teflon sheets sound like a good idea, I'll check that out, thanks.
